# Pandas DataFrame apply or map dictionary valueassign column to function of MultiIndex value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, multi-index

I want to map (via dictionary) part of a MultiIndex DataFrame to a column.  Is there a way to do that in a single step?

For example, with the following sample DataFrame:

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], np.arange(1, 11, 1)], names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30), i, columns=['Vals'])
```

and sample map:

```
a = list('abcdefghijk')
m = {}
for i in range(0,11):
    m[i] = a[i]
```

I want to create a column X containing the letter associated with the second index level:

```
df.assign(X=m[df.index.get_level_values('Num').values])
```

But that doesn't work, and neither does:

```
df['X'] = df.index.map(lambda x: m[x[1]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the second level with `get_level_values`, convert to a `Series`, and call `map`/`replace` -

```
df['X'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).to_series().map(m).values
```

Or,

```
df['X'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).to_series().replace(m).values
```

Alternatively (inspired by OP), you can call `map` on `df.index.get_level_values`, and pass a callable (in this case, it would be `m.get`) -

```
df['X'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).map(m.get)
```

```
df

              Vals  X
Name Num             
A    1    2.731237  b
     2    0.180595  c
     3   -1.428064  d
     4   -0.622806  e
     5    0.948709  f
     6   -1.383310  g
     7    0.177631  h
     8   -1.071445  i
     9   -0.183859  j
     10   1.480641  k
B    1   -1.036380  b
     2    1.031757  c
     3    0.542989  d
     4   -0.933676  e
     5   -0.540661  f
     6   -0.506969  g
     7    0.572705  h
     8   -1.363675  i
     9   -0.588765  j
     10   0.998691  k
C    1   -0.471536  b
     2   -1.361124  c
     3   -0.382200  d
     4    0.694174  e
     5    1.077779  f
     6   -0.501285  g
     7    0.961986  h
     8   -0.285009  i
     9    1.385881  j
     10   1.490152  k
```

Here, I've got to call `.values` because I want to be able to assign the result back to the dataframe without indexing alignment issues.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another shorthand that works:

```
df['X'] = df.index.map(lambda x: m.get(x[1]))
```

It is not invalid to use a dictionary in a lambda like that, it's just that (apparently) the index notation of dictionary value (e.g., `m[x[1]]`) lookup doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to figure out a much shorter variant for mine: `df.index.get_level_values(1).map(m.get)`

Answer (score 2):

`rename` it then assign it back

```
df['New']=df.rename(index=m,level=1).index.get_level_values(1)
df
Out[132]: 
              Vals New
Name Num              
A    1   -0.906266   b
     2    0.321047   c
     3    0.227720   d
     4    3.040522   e
     5    0.604392   f
     6    1.394153   g
     7   -0.640342   h
     8   -0.812858   i
     9   -1.142764   j
     10   0.744968   k
B    1    0.956003   b
     2    0.064266   c
     3    0.042286   d
     4   -1.089578   e
     5    0.534922   f
     6   -0.545524   g
     7    0.102778   h
     8   -1.691460   i
     9   -1.980935   j
     10   1.226609   k
C    1    0.871654   b
     2    0.396818   c
     3    0.691537   d
     4    1.923429   e
     5    0.239363   f
     6   -0.669168   g
     7   -0.168082   h
     8    0.209918   i
     9    0.205527   j
     10   0.490754   k
```